# DI with Lambda Functions

Tags: simple-injector

I have a lambda function (in AWS, but should be similar to Azure Functions). The scenario I have is that some classes are instance specific(i.e. contains data that is specific to the call).

So I tried the following approaches.

Approach 1:

This is what I started with and it works.

```
private Container container;
void FunctionHandler(params)
{
    InitializeDI()
}

void InitializeDI()
{

    container = new Container();
    //Register all types
    ...
//This is a class that contains some instance specific data, so the same instance is being passed around.
var logg = FileLogger();
    logg.session = SessionData;
    container.RegisterInstance<ILogger>(logg);
}
```

I use constructor injection and everything works fine. Only issue I see is that the container graph is rebuilt every time my Lambda function is called.

Approach 2:

```
private static Container container;
void FunctionHandler(params)
{
    InitializeDI()
}

void InitializeDI()
{
    if (container == null)
    {
        container = new Container();
        //Register all types
        ...
    }

    //This is a class that contains some instance specific data, so the same instance is being passed around.
    var logg = FileLogger();
    logg.session = SessionData;
    container.RegisterInstance<ILogger>(logg);
}
```

Here the container is static and will be created only when the first function is called (ie. Lambda is cold started) and then the environment will reuse the loaded class and so container should already be available.
The only problem is when the second call comes in, ILogger will already have been registered in the graph and will not register again. So this approach does not work at all.

Approach 2.1

```
void InitializeDI()
{
    if (container == null)
    {
        container = new Container();
        //Register all types
        ...
    }
    var logg = FileLogger();
    container.RegisterInstance<ILogger>(logg);
}
//This is a class that contains some instance specific data, so the same instance is being passed around.
logg.session = SessionData;
}
```

I thought of just registering it once, but changing the session data only when reusing, but then Functions can be re-entrant, which means, another function may get the wrong session data??

Is there a way to get around having to re-build the object graph every time but still have call-specific class injection work too?

Thanks

Comment: The root of your trouble is the fact that you're injecting runtime data into the object graph during construction: https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2015/code-smell-injecting-runtime-data-into-components/

Comment: Thanks @Steven, that makes sense.. I started out with passing the information down the chain, but it became quite complex as the number of functions that may need this information increased and so info needs to flow down a number of layers. So I thought it may make sense to inject these into constructors instead of having those as parameters.